# isupper() and isdigit() not working together

Tags: python, function, passwords, uppercase

I am trying to create a simple passwprd application and I want to check if my password meets some requierments. I want it to have both an uppercase letter and a digit somewhere. I am storing each letter of the password in a list using a for loop and I then check if each element in the list is uppercase. But when I, in the if statement that checks if the letter is uppercase, add a new if statemnt checking if one of the characters is a digit the if statement doesn’t return anything.

```
def check_password():
    characters = []

    if len(password_entry.get()) >= 8:
        for i in range (len(password_entry.get())):
            characters.append(password_entry.get()[i])
            if characters[i].isupper():
                if characters[i].isdigit():
                    register_user()
                    print("password valid")
            else:
                password_not_valid_upper()
    else:
        password_not_valid_length()
```

Comment: How do you expect something to be True for `isupper` and `isdigit`?

Comment: And you don't check the whole string before coming to the conclusion that there are no upper characters present. If the first character is not uppercase you call `password_not_valid_upper`, even if all of the following characters are all uppercase. You want something like `if not any(character.isupper() for character in password_entry.get()):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking that the character is uppercase, and if it is you're then checking if it's a digit.  It can't be both so you're always falling through to the else password_not_valid_upper().